# Is there a way to check if a file/folder in Dropbox has a shared link without creating one?

Tags: dropbox

We want to use the Dropbox REST API to check if a file/folder has a shared link, and if so what permissions it has (e.g. is it password protected).

The only relevant API call seems to be [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares), which creates a public shared link if no shared link already exists. Calling it with the GET http verb also has the side effect.

Is there a way to check the shared link status without changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to just get shared link status/metadata like this on the Dropbox API, but we're tracking this as a feature request.

Comment: is this answer still current?

Comment: @user2682863 No, this is no longer current. This question and answer was written for Dropbox API v1. Dropbox now offers [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) with more functionality. For example, you can use [/2/sharing/list_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links) to check if a shared link already exists (and get the shared link metadata if so) for any particular file or folder, without creating a shared link for it.